# jsfiddle how do I get the scrollTop value inside a fiddle

Tags: jquery, scroll, jsfiddle

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lj_tang/qynvg44b/1/)

I want the classes to change when the `scrolltop` reaches the values specified in the if statement...

I don't know what stupid mistake I have made that I can't get it to work

Comment: Did you take a look at [the console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337/19742)?

Comment: yeah and I can't find it. I am trying to understand jsfiddle for better examples but some code that work in other fiddles won't do it when I use them

Comment: One thing to note - once youve digested the good answer below. You have specified `background-color:green` on the id `container`. It doesnt matter what class you apply afterwards, your background color will not change as the style against the id takes precendent over the styles applied by class. This is just the ways css works, and has nothing to do with the code.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, stupid rookie mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

- I don't think jQuery has an `onscroll` function
- You have a missing closing bracket on your second if `$('#main'` <- here
- Staying with that if, you have missed the brackets off the scrollTop function
- You are checking the scrollTop value of main - it will always be 0 as it never scrolls, you are scrolling the window

Try the following (changes in comments);

```js
$(window).on('scroll', function() { // change to scroll rather than onscroll
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(); // get scroll top of the thing that is scrolling and cache for better performance
  if (scrollTop > 100) {
    $("#container").addClass("red");
  } else if (scrollTop > 500) {
    $("#container").removeClass("red").addClass("blue"); // chain actions
  } else {
    $("#container").removeClass("red blue"); // you can pass two classes into this
  }
});
```

If you use this in your fiddle and inspect the container, you will see the class get added (you won't see it change colour as it goes off screen before the class changes)

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"` in your snippet - you forgot to select jQuery and include the relevant html

Comment: @Jamiec Sorry, not meant to be a snippet - just fixing the OP code

Comment: yes, but if you try it, you'll see that it still does not work - the background does not change from green because that css is specified against an id, and takes precedent over the `.red` class.

Comment: @Jamiec rtfq, it doesn't say anything about changing colours, just classes.  IF OP wants the full fiddle fixing, well, then they ought to pay someone as that fiddle has a lot of errors

Comment: (interpret)tfq, And please swearing is unecessary! Actually running the code you put in answers stops you looking like a fool.

Comment: thank you for your answer and I apologize... new to programming