# Add/Remove header class on scroll, and caching the header - am I doing it right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this script to change the header's color when scrolling the page to the top. It should also cache the header selector so it won't query the DOM every time it scrolls.
It works, but am I writing it right, especially on the caching part?
Also, does it make sense to you caching such a short piece of CSS?
I'm not a JS developer and I'm trying to understand how to do it properly. Thanks.

```js
$(function() {
    //caches jQuery object header
    var header = $(".header");
    //
    $(document).on('scroll', function(){
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 30) {
            $('header').addClass('header-scroll-top');
        } else {
            $('header').removeClass('header-scroll-top');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.header-scroll-top {
    background-color: #131313;
}

   header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you make your code run here on stackoverflow and/or create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593827/jsfiddle-how-do-i-get-the-scrolltop-value-inside-a-fiddle

Comment: Please review your question, can't see anywhere cache being used

Comment: @natel , the second part of JS <code>$(document).on<code> is working fine at my hands, but I'm not sure about the first part <code>var header = $(".header");<code> which should cache the header so it won't query the DOM every time it scrolls.

Comment: @Viney, so the first part <code>var header = $(".header");<code> is not caching at all? If so, every time the page will scroll up the DOM will be queried? How can I avoid that?

Comment: Declare `var header = $(".header");` outside of ready handler then use `header.addClass('header-scroll-top');` instead of `$('header').addClass('header-scroll-top');`

Comment: @Viney, as per your instructions I ended up with this which is working at my end
<code>
$(function() {
    var header = $(".header");
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 30) {
            header.addClass('header-scroll-top');
        } else {
            header.removeClass('header-scroll-top');
        }
    });
});
<code>
But I don't understand where I can declare <code>var header = $(".header");<code> outside of ready handler. Sorry, I'm still trying to figure out how JS works.

Comment: Well @rocco by that I meant making it a global variable but looks like it doesn't need to be! cheers